# UIImage from NSData with wrong orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata, uiimageorientation

My app pick a photo from camera roll and store it as `NSData`.
When I need to show the image in my app I create the `UIImage` from `NSData`.

If the original photo is an image I save from web, google image or so, the `UIImage` has right orientation, if the original photo is a portrait photo I shoot with the iPhone, the `UIImage` is rotated 90 degrees left.

I cannot imagine how to know which photo needs to rotate and which are OK.

any help is appreciated.

the code I use to save image as NSData in a coredata entity:

```
 asset.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (input, info) in
      if let imgurl = input?.fullSizeImageURL {
           let img = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: imgurl)!)
           self.gearImage = img
           self.photoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
           self.photoImageView.image = self.gearImage
       }
}
```

then I save the NSData in coredata:

```
if self.gearImage != nil {
    newItem.cgPhoto = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.gearImage!)
}
```

When I have to show the image I fetch the coredata entity and:

```
let img = UIImage(data: self.imageData)
```

And here is the problem. If the phasset fullSizeImageOrientation is null or 1 the image is OK, else has wrong rotation.

Max

Comment: Please post code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is due to the format in which you generate the data from picture. Try convert it from `jpg` format first because not all formats contain information about the rotation of the image. Try something like this:

```
var imageData: NSData?
if let _jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0) {
    imageData = _jpgData
} else if let _pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    imageData = _pngData
}
```

Comment: changing to UIImageJPEGRepresentation works but I'm facing the problem since I moved from ALAsset to Photos.